# javascript how to increase height by em units

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I increase the height of an html element, by a certain number of em units, using JavaScript?

Here's an example that doesn't work, but demonstrates what I'm trying to do. In the body of an html page:

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" style="height:10em" onclick="test()"></textarea>
```

Then, in the script:

```
function test() {
    // get the height, assign to var x
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.height;

    // calculate height increase by 10 em
    x += "10em";

    // increase the height by amount calculated
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.height = x;
}
```

I want to increase by em units, not pixels.

Comment: Well, in javascript `"10em" + "10em"` is the same as `"10em10em"`, that's what strings do ?

Comment: why not just do `(x += 10) + 'em'`

Comment: @JohnRuddell Because `style.height` (which is stored in `x`) returns a string, not a number. You have to parse the string into a number first. (Unless you are using CSS to do the calculation, as in Oriol's answer…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the computed style and use `calc` to sum:

```css
el.style.height = 'calc(' + getComputedStyle(el).height + ' + 10em)';
```

```js
var el = document.querySelector('textarea');
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  el.style.height = 'calc(' + getComputedStyle(el).height + ' + 1em)';
}
```

```html
<button>Increase height</button><br />
<textarea style="height:10em"></textarea>
```

Comment: Plus 1. This solution doesn't require an inline style to already be set on the element.

Comment: And if present, the inline style is not required to be in `em`. Any unit would work, e.g. `px`, `mm`, ...

Comment: Ah yes, I had just noticed that problem on another solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the style back, it's a string, and then you add another string, it's like

```
var x = "10em" + "10em";
```

and `x` ends up being `10em10em`, which is invalid. You'll have to work with numbers.

```
function test() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.height;

    x = parseFloat( x.replace(/\D/g, '') );

    x += 10;

    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.height = x + "em";
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/71udL11s/)

Comment: Why did you add an additional `replace` call? Shouldn't be `parseInt`/`parseFloat` be sufficent?

Comment: Parsing letters isn't what it's intended for, I like to remove those first.

Comment: [Fiddle that actually calls the function shown](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/71udL11s/1/).

Comment: @adeneo I think `parseFloat` is precisely intended for parsing a number from a string with both numbers and letters. Otherwise you can just use `Number` or the unary `+`.

Comment: It's intended for numbers, but ignores unknown characters and returns the value parsed up to the unknown character, which means it can cause issues. In this case it wouldn't as the letters are at the end of the string, but I think it's still good practice to try and parse numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the unit before adding numbers and then append the unit again afterwards:

```
function test() {
    // get the height, assign to var x
    var x = parseInt( document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.height );

    // calculate height increase by 10 em
    x += 10;

    // increase the height by amount calculated
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.height = x + "em";
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: What if the height in the inline style uses units other than `em`s?