# How to add "5px " to the current fontsize in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the font size of a class on click my only problem is that I don't want to change the fontSize to a fixed number, but instead I want to add "5px" to the already current fontSize.

JavaScript:

```js
function bigger() {
  var e, i;
  e = document.querySelectorAll(".example");
  for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].style.fontSize = "20px";
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript how to increase height by em units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021935/javascript-how-to-increase-height-by-em-units)

Comment: No it doesn't, because that method does not work for .querySelectorAll

Comment: What?? How does `querySelectorAll()` matter?

Comment: I want to add "5px" to the currentSize but the method suggested in the article above is setting the font size as a variable and then calling it in the function but that does not work in my case, because I'm using a '0' loop to affect all of the elements in the example class. Also I'm just a beginner and don't know how to apply this to my own code.

Comment: I fail to understand your point

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use css variables
sample code:

```js
(function()
  {
  const
      fSzProp = '--fsize'
    , Root    = document.documentElement
    , gRoot   = getComputedStyle(Root)
    , btnInc  = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-inc-font]')
    ;
  var fSizeVal = parseInt(gRoot.getPropertyValue(fSzProp))
    ;
  btnInc.forEach(bt=> bt.onclick=()=>
    {
    fSizeVal = Math.max( 6 , (fSizeVal + Number(bt.dataset.incFont)))
    Root.style.setProperty(fSzProp,  `${fSizeVal}px`)
    })
  }
)()
```

```css
:root {
  --fsize : 16px;
  }
.elements {
  font-size : var(--fsize );
}
```

```html
<p>Set Font to : 
  <button data-inc-font="+5"> + 5px </button>
  <button data-inc-font="-5"> - 5px </button>
</p>

<p class="elements"> hello world 1</p>

<p class="elements"> hello world 2</p>
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not want to use a selector I want to add to the currentSize "5px".

Comment: @PierreKhalil  I changed my answer